# Creating a scikit-learn package

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am creating a new classifier and wanting to add it into sklearn library.

I am following a template provided by sklearn but I'm stuck at Step 1. Step 1 is "Download and setup your repository" (see link below).

https://sklearn-template.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html

1) What is Step 1 used for?

2) Are the lines of codes, for eg. the ones below to be run in Python or somewhere else?

```
$ git clone https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/project-template.git

$ git grep skltemplate
$ git grep sklearn-template

$ cd project-template
$ rm -rf .git
```

3) Going through line by line under Step 1 ("Download and setup your repository"), can someone explain what is the logic step by step and what is it doing?

Many thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, these are the steps for creating a [github](https://github.com/) repository. In order to contirbute to most python projects, you will write your code, save it in github, and issue a request to the project's owners to import it from your github into theirs

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean the eg. lines of codes I had mentioned above are not Python codes to run?

Comment: If they are not Python codes, where should they be run in?

Comment: They _are_ python code, but _stored_ on github. It would be worth finding a github book or tutorial to go through to understand the service and process better

Comment: Ok many thanks for this.